# Why can't I pass args with a "-" to my node module from the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am running my module from a script in `package.json`. When I add command line arguments like below, it only passes the args that don't start with a minus (-):

```
npm run myscript -one two
```

The args I get are:

```
[
    '/home/myhome/apps/node-v6.4.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
    '/home/myhome/Development/code/node_modules/.bin/mymodule',
    'two'
]
```

Any arg I add with one or more minus characters at the beginning aren't passed. Even if I put them in quotes like `npm run myscript "--one two"` or `npm run myscript "--one" two` - it still won't send it to my module.

How do I get those command line args?

Comment: Have you tried `npm run myscript -- -one two` ? See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script .

Comment: I just discovered that. It seems like a messy hack, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more searching and testing, it appears the only way to pass them through is to prefix your args with `-- -arg something`. **Notice the space after the `--`**. Without that space, it won't work. For example, this will ***not*** pass the arg to you: `npm run myscript --ignore -arg e`. You have to do it like:

```
npm run myscript -- -one two
```

See: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3494#issue-14832427

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass like this, then you can capture it using  `process.env.`

```
npm run myscript --one=somevalue --two=somevalue
```

Comment: It works... for me.. removed the quotes... btw i guess you have got the answer...

Comment: Just did it again, still doesn't work for me. What npm version do you have? (I have 3.10.3 and my node is 6.4.0)

Comment: Maybe they updated how it works in the later version?